# Get all object from array of objects having similar value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, iteration

Let say I have a 5 objects like so in an array:

```
var myObjects = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 1, b: 6}, {a: 3, b: 8}, {a: 1, b: 9}];
```

How can I iterate though this myObjects and get objects having similar value `a = 1`. eg. `{a: 1, b: 2},{a: 1, b: 6},{a: 1, b: 9}` as a result?

Comment: If you don't know the value of `a` to search for then provide an example of the result you expect

Comment: i want to get {a: 1, b: 2},{a: 1, b: 6},{a: 1, b: 9} as a result array of objects because in these objects a is equal to 1 and same is true for any other values

Comment: But you said you don't know the value of `a`... so what is the rule to filter value = 1? How should the code know to remove a = 3? they won't be removed by magic, you need to define your rules. Why shouldn't the result be `{a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 3, b: 8}` for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var result = myObjects.filter(function(e) {
    return e.a === 1;
});
```

**MDN** provides a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility) for old browsers which don't support this method.

If you want to group objects based on property `a`, then you may use the following approach:

```
var result = {};

for (var i = 0, len = myObjects.length; i < len; i++) {
    var obj = myObjects[i];

    if (result[obj.a] === undefined) {
        result[obj.a] = [];
    }

    result[obj.a].push(obj);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for reply but i have tried this, but in my case I don't know the value of 'a', i have just given that for clearity

Comment: @BijayRai Then the solution will be a bit more advanced. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Extending on @VisioN's answer: You can use a factory function that itself returns a function to filter by:

```
function filterAByValue(value) {
  return function(item) {
    return item.a === value;
  };
}

var result = myObjects.filter(filterAByValue(1));
```

Or even make the property variable:

```
function filterPropertyByValue(property, value) {
  return function(item) {
    return item[property] === value;
  };
}

var result = myObjects.filter(filterPropertyByValue("a", 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var index[];
for(i=0;i<obj.lenght;i++)
{
    if(obj[i].a==1)
    {
       index.push(i);
       //you even can push obj[i] to some other array and use it
    }
}
```